# Magento2: not able to place order

Tags: magento2, orders, payment-methods

I am not able to place order using Cash on Delivery. it takes very long time to and not processing the order, it comes back to the cart with items listed.

this site loads very slow can, please let me know any observations to improve the speed of the http://www.alaincooponline.com

**Here is the screenshot after clicking on place order.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Teja, Please check and let me know your observations

Comment: Thanks, Can u please check this module. its custom Payment module with drop-down list. [Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12IpO3fh-8MfJnMTwHlz26vY7puy5biEg/view)

Comment: Please check log fies.

Comment: Can you please confirm that log files are located in magentoroot/var/log- dafalut.log, exception.log & system.log

Comment: Yes, log files located in {{magento root}}/var/log/exception.log OR system.log OR debug.log.

Comment: I checked the Log it add new lines in [System.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eD1YrGpEY8RUIdeCiN9KhyF_CMd5Ew0q) only.

Comment: Here is the last few lines newly added when i tested in  [System.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sNKUQfhAObjajBvlUWW7Dp6dgyudLnAg). Please let me know what can i do.

Comment: Have you customized something related to **ShippingAddress**?

Comment: @kunj I did not customized anything in Shipping Address. please check the site [here](http://www.alaincooponline.com).

Answer (score 0):

You have the error related to memory while running `rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information` on place order.

I found below error in AJax, while tried to plcae order on your website, I have added error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Out of memory (allocated 2847145984) (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in <b>/home/stagingalainadm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php</b> on line <b>57</b><br />
```

Comment: here is the memory details mentioned in my .htaccess     


## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 2048M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

Comment: Please let me know what can be done to fix this.

Comment: Either your website's server configuration not proper or something is wrong with the code, Have you enabled Magento 2 caching or added any other caching for the website?

Comment: I was not able to figure out what was the problem. I have setup new vertion in my system. now I am having problem with my custom Payment Module [This question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225832/magento2-how-to-pass-data-to-save-in-table-in-custom-payment-method)

Comment: How Can i find if there was any problem with server configuration

Comment: When i run this Url http://www.alaincooponline.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information with user login it shows XML with products list and Payment methods. any idea how can it be fixed.

Comment: It is rest API, it will not run in the browser.

Comment: how can i fix this error now .?

Comment: You have to trace your code or ask your server provider about server configuration. have you tried Magento 2 caching?

Comment: Maybe the issue in your custom theme, you can try to disable it.

Comment: Yes, I have used CLI commands to clear Cache , bin/magento Cache:clean & flush. what should I do more.