# Magento2: How to compile custom payment module

Tags: magento2, module, compilation

I am new to magento, currently working on a custom payment module created by another Developer. I am facting hard time to understand module.

This module has A drop-down List before placing order, But I change the option, it is not Displaying updated list, I could see old List.

I have tried below

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

But non of this worked. i whated to know how I can compile the module.

Please check this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225832/magento2-custom-payment-module-with-drop-down-list-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment314961_225832) I Could not able to Fix this problem.

Comment: try php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: You enable developer mode and check the error log

Answer (score 0):

You can compile by the following command:

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Then run:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>   php bin/magento
>   cache:flush

Comment: I have followed the steps, but i did not work. Can you please check the question once I have edited. Given link to another link of my question.

Answer (score 0):

No. That is not possible with tools shipped with Magento now.

Explanation: We have to distinguish code generation and compilation. Compiler does both. For both operations we need to read configuration of all other magento modules, otherwise their output will be incorrect or not full.

Compilation for one module does not make sense, as magento will not work with compiled configuration for one module only.

Generation for one module might make sense, but we will have to read configuration and constructor signatures from all other installed modules anyway. Without it not all code might be generated. So such operation would not be much faster than full compilation. We might think of it, but I think the bug you referenced will be fixed before the command is implemented.

Comment: Can you please check the question once I have edited. Given link to another link of my question.